# how to get the rows from two table instead of one when their is sure that they exist in one

Tags: sql, mysql, database, command

i have two table in mysql database. the row have primary key ID 5 is sure that exist in one or if not then exist in 2

how i can retrive them by making a command in MySQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your tables have the same structure, you could do this using UNION ALL:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table1 WHERE ID = 5
UNION ALL
SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM table2 WHERE ID = 5
LIMIT 1
```

You could also consider changing your schema so that you only have one table with a field to store whether it is type one or type two.

Comment: ALSO: You can use the AS clause to rename columns on the fly. The types of the returned data must match for the columns in each select.